# Application freezing when loading references

Tags: c#, ikvm

I am using IKVM with a custom dll library written in java (and thus converted with ikvmc). Now the problem is, these references don't seem to load on startup, but only when it's first needed.

For example when I first initialize a type in the library. It then loads all of the IKVM assemblies (which are quite a lot) and it seems to freeze my application/form.

This is kind of user unfriendly, so I'd be happy to know if there was any way to avoid this "lag". It makes the user feel like the program is about to crash.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try to force loading earlier from background thread by referencing an object yourself... Hopefully someone will provide link/info on whether assembly loading require global freeze of app or not...

Comment: If there is no other way around this, i guess this might be a way. Although i need those objects quite fast after startup, if not directly..

Comment: EDIT: That does not seem to work, I initialize some useless type in a thread from the library but it doesn't load the references. It only loads them when I need them in my main form window.